# Laravel validate array of objects

Tags: laravel

I wonder if its possible to validate a array of objects in Laravel?
I have built a form looking like a excell page using vue, so the user can edit many rows that later gets uploaded.

The data that I wish to validate when posting to my controller looks like this:

```
rows[
0 {
  title: "my title",
  post: "my post text"
},
1 {
 title: "my title",
  post: "my post text"
},
2 {
 title: "my title",
  post: "my post text"
}
]
```

So for example how can I add a required rule to each input?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use array validation of Laravel.

eg.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'row.*.title' => 'required',
    'row.*.post' => 'required',
]);
```

You can find more about Laravel array validation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays)

Comment: The validation always passes when I try that

Comment: Same here! It does not return an error if any!

Comment: can you post a sample data ?

Comment: It always passes. I don't think this is a correct answer.

Comment: THIS IS NOT CORRECT! IT ALWAYS PASSES.

Answer (score 13):

The approved answer works if your posting an array, however to take it a step further, I am needing to save multiple arrays. While that approach would work if I make two separate endpoints, what if I want to save everything inside one `DB::transaction`?

Viola:

```
// POST:
{
    "array1": [
        { "key1": "string", "key2": 1 },
        { "key1": "string", "key2": 0 }
    ],
    "array2": [
        { "key3": "string", "key4": 1 },
        { "key3": "string", "key4": 0 }
    ]
}
```

```
// SERVER:
$this->validate($request, [
    'array1' => 'present|array',
    'array2' => 'present|array',
    'array1.*.key1' => 'required|string',
    'array1.*.key2' => 'required|integer',
    'array2.*.key3' => 'required|string',
    'array2.*.key4' => 'required|integer'
]);

DB::transaction(function() use($request) {
    foreach($request['array1'] as $x){
        // ...do stuff here
    };
});
```

Note: `'present|array'` accepts empty arrays whereas `'required|array'` would reject them.

Comment: Also, note: you can validate an array that is not inside of a parent object like this: `$this->validate($request, [ '*.key' => 'required|string' ]);`

Answer (score 2):

Laravel validations works fine if the elements of the array are associative arrays, but if they are objects it will fail, and sometimes you want to keep your data as objects for further manipulations.

I created the following custom rule

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

/**
 * Valida in arreglo de objetos
 * 
 * Si bien Laravel puede validar arrays, solo funciona
 * si sus elementos son arreglos asociativos, cuando son 
 * objetos la regla no se aplica
 */
class ArrayOfObjects implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Reglas de validacion
     */
    private array $rules;

    /**
     * Mensaje de error
     */
    private string $error;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $rules)
    {
        $this->rules = $rules;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        foreach ($this->rules as $property => $property_rules)
        {
            $rules = [$property => $property_rules];

            if (isset($value->{$property}))
            {
                $data = [$property => $value->{$property}];

                $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

                if ($validator->fails())
                {
                    $this->error = $validator->errors()->first($property);

                    // Detener el loop si hay un error
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (in_array('required', $property_rules))
                {
                    $this->error = __('validation.required', ['attribute' => $property]);

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;        
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return $this->error;
    }
}
```

Its ussage in a controller for example

```php
public function store (Request $request)
{
  $object_rules = [
    'attr_1' => ['required', 'string'],
    'attr_2' => ['required', 'numeric']
  ];

  $request->validate([
    'array.*' => new ArrayOfObjects($object_rules)
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    '*.title' => 'required',
    '*.post' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?